# Twitter Bootstrap Jumbotron issue on portrait

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Using Bootstrap 3 Jumbotron example, when viewing on iPad (portrait), somehow the Jumbotron gets too wide and goes beyond the viewport. Just a few pixels, it's true, but still. This does not happen while viewing on landscape or on iPhone, either portrait or landscape.

I thought I had messed up with CSS, but turned out this also happens on Bootstrap official example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

Any idea what can be done to fix it?

Comment: Can you give some code ?

Comment: The code is in the example provided by twitter: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/ The same problem that happens there, happens on my page.

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.jumbotron` has `padding: 30px;` which combined with the `width: 750px;` of `.container` adds up to 810px. Which is apparently bit too wide for the iPad.

A workaround would be to add a rule like this to your CSS:

```
.jumbotron .container{
    max-width:750px;
    width: auto;
}
```

**Edit:** Turns out there is already a bug report about this on Github: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11390 – For the meanwhile the code above should fix it.